# external array definition

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, definition, extern

I would like to define array of strings in different cpp file, but there seems to be some discrepancy between definition and declaration when I try to make pointer (array element) also const. Using the same definition as declaration seems to work fine, so I suspect initialization is not an issue. In the code below I have commented out offending const - so it will compile, but  if const is un-commented, linker (tested with g++ 4.6 & VS10) will not find ext_string_array.

### main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

const char* const string_array[2] =
{
  "aaa",
  "bbb"
};

extern const char* /*const*/ ext_string_array[2]; // <- offending const

int main()
{
  std::cout << string_array[0];
  std::cout << ext_string_array[0];
}
```

---

### definition.cpp:

```
const char* /*const*/ ext_string_array[2] = // <- offending const
{
  "aaa",
  "bbb"
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In this context const also means static, unless you also specify extern. Change your .cpp file to this

```
extern const char* const ext_string_array[2] =
{
  "aaa",
  "bbb"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ 2003, *3.5 Program and Linkage*, *3*:

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.5) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>   [...]
>
> — an object or reference that is explicitly declared const and neither explicitly declared  extern nor previously declared to have external linkage; [...]

So you need an explicit `extern` in the declaration..